# Jmeter issue executing upload file request in linux

Tags: linux, jmeter, filepath

In a jmeter script I upload an image and it works fine on Windows using HTTP request Files Upload
[SEE IMAGE HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWZ47.png)

but when executing it from the linux injectors (through Jenkins pipeline), it puts these signs right in front of the photo name:

**. \ /**

so when I execute it looks for the image path like this. \ / 23001715994600000001_17.jpeg (No such file or directory)
and the image, of course is not found due to the slashes.
I've tried to pass the path through a variable and it has the same behavior...

```
do you know why it could happen?

do you think it could be something from Linux?

or rather from JMeter?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMeter [shouldn't add any extra characters](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.3/src/core/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/services/FileServer.java#L254) to the file name, just remember to copy the file(s) you're going to upload to "bin" folder of your JMeter installation on all the injector(s), otherwise JMeter won't be able to upload the file.

If you're [running JMeter in distributed mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter) remember that JMeter master only transfers the [.jmx script](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JmxTestPlan) itself to the slaves, any external data (CSV files, properties, files used for uploading, etc.) are not transferred.

If you're using [Directory Listing Config](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/directory-listing/DirectoryListing.md) - make sure to tick `Use full path` box